# How to have the ID category selected in select dropdown?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database table which has all the projects listed in here with a column named "projCat" which is an ID field that relates to another table called projectcats.

The projects table projCat has an ID which relates to the projectscat ID.

```
<li class="field"><h2>Select Project Sector?</h2>
<select name="projCat" id="projCat" class="input">
<?php 
    $cat = $_GET['cat'];
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projectscat");

    $checked == '$cat' ? 'selected' : '';

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($query1)){
        echo "<option value=\"" . $row1->projCatID . "\"" . $checked . ">" . $row1->projCatTitle . "</option>\n";
    }
?>
</select></li>
```

The outcome I would like to have is a list of all the project categories but get the projCat so it highlights this category first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <li class="field"><h2>Select Project Sector? <?php echo $row->projCat;?></h2>
    <select name="projCat" id="projCat" class="input">
    <?php 
        $cat = $_GET['cat'];
        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projectscat");
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($query1)){
            echo "<option value='" . $row1->projCatID . "' selected='";

            if($cat == $row1->[your category in table]) {
                echo "selected";
            } else {
                echo '';
            }
            echo "'>" . $row1->projCatTitle . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
    </select></li>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer to my question. I have used your code but it shows selected for every category in the drop-down.

Comment: @Craig check it now. Changed '$cat' to $cat

Comment: @medCoder no. because if a data exists in $cat the selected is stored to $checked, which is the same for all options.

Comment: ô yes, i was wrong, i updated the code, replacing the test at the right place

Comment: @medCoder `$_GET['cat'`] is same dude. Even if you put in the while loop `$cat` doesnt change

Comment: @IamNewbie, many thanks for your help and providing code, it works great thanks, I just had to make a few tweaks to your code.

Answer (score 0):

From the code of IamNewbie

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($query1)){
     $checked = $cat ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value='" . $row1->projCatID . "' " . $checked . ">" . $row1->projCatTitle . "</option>";
}
```